# App doesn't fill iPhone X screen when from the app store

Tags: iphone-x

I have an app running in landscape mode only.
I've been modifying it to adapt to the iPhone X layout, filling the screen but only operate within the safe are atc. 
When I develop and test my app starting it on the actual device from xcode, all looks fine and it uses the full iPhone X screen. But when my app is released through the app store, it only uses part of the screen. Even the splash screen is only inside the safe area, but in full screen while testing via xcode.

Any ideas what's wrong/missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved.** 
I have two target that build from the same source. I was testing one through xcode and the other through TestFlight.

It's an old project from before storyboard was introduced, so they didn't have a launch screen storyboard. I had added one for the one target to make it work with the iPhone X, but not for the other. Now that both have a launch screen storyboard, all works fine.

Comment: So you had to convert all your .xibs into Storyboard ? sounds like a ton of work.

Comment: No, I kept all my .xibs. I just added a launch storyboard file.

Comment: I've got this issue, but I'm having trouble finding what you've changed to get it to work.  Can you provide a link or explanation?